# How to add different Custom Cells in TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row, cell

I have multiple custom cells. I subclass two of them. I want to display different cells with different identifiers with storyboards. So far using an array I was able to show one subclass cell but I'm having an issue with the row count and the technique to show multiple cells. I'm using a delay to keep adding and updating my table.

```
    NSMutableArray *conv1;
    NSString *l1;
    NSString *l2;
    NSString *l3;
    NSMutableArray *allDialogue;
    NSMutableArray *conv2;
}

@end

@implementation PlotController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    conv1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    conv2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    allDialogue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [allDialogue addObjectsFromArray:conv1];
    [allDialogue addObjectsFromArray:conv2];
    l1 = @"converstaion1";
    l2 = @"converstaion2";
    l3 = @"converstaion3";
    _tableV.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self performSelector:@selector(delay) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    [self performSelector:@selector(delay2) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

tableview config

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MainStoryDialogue *dialogueCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PDialogue"];

    dialogueCell.textHere.text = [allDialogue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableV beginUpdates];
    [self.tableV endUpdates];

    return dialogueCell;
}
```

The second issue is the row count

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [allDialogue count];
}
```

Comment: adding multiple custom cells like i stated

Comment: As an aside, the begin and end updates calls in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` table view controller lifecycle method do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think, to be able to show more than one custom cell in the table view, first, in your storyboard you need to click on your tableView and under the attribute inspector you will see a field called Prototype Cells. Select the number of different cells that you would like to use, customize them as you please, create a TableViewCell class for each, make all the appropriate connections, and set a unique identifier for each cell. Having done that, in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method (based on whatever condition) you can instantiate that specific cell that you want to have for a given row using the custom cell class that you created and the appropriate cell identifier.

so for example:

```
if (indexpath.row == 1) {
    MainStoryDialogue *dialogueCell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PDialogue"];

//do all appropriate things if you have this cell
} else {
    CustomCell2 *customCell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell2"];

//do all appropriate things if you had this cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for the great feedback but it didn't work, it worked until the rows were updated im guessing its for the        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [allDialogue count];
}        What can i replace this with

Comment: I'm updating simply by adding to the array with a delay

Comment: okay so when you update and add something to your array, call [self.tableView reloadData]; where tableView is the reference to the UITableView in your app.

Comment: and what is the purpose of the delay?

Comment: In my delay i call `[self.tableView reloadData]` and add to the array     `[conv1 addObject:@"addition"];`         the delay is to see it update automatically in a specific time